# What is the “Safety Tips” component present on chrome://components?

Tags: google-chrome, virus, malware, malware-removal

I'm worried about a component I've seen on my [chrome://components](http://chrome://components) list. It's name is **Safety Tips** (see the [Image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6EZl.png)).

Is it malware or a virus of any kind? How do I uninstall it?

My operating System is Ubuntu Mate 18.04

Comment: It’s new in Chrome 77.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safety Tips seems to be a work in progress that will give warnings for the current
page, as well as gather some data about downloads from the page.
It seems that it will not be available for all webpages.

The only way for the moment to get a glimpse of what it will do, is by reading
Chromium bug reports for this component.

[**Issue 984725: Implement client-side heuristics for Safety Tips**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=984725)

> Safety Tips: add lookalike heuristic checking.
>
> This CL adds lookalike heuristic checking to safety tips. A safety tip
>   is only triggered when a lookalike domain is identified, but an
>   interstitial would NOT be triggered. In practice, this means a safety
>   tip is triggered when:
>
> - there's an edit distance of 1 to a top or engaged domain, or
> - there's skeleton similarity to a non-top-500 top domain.

My guess that this a metric to detect domain names that are very
similar to well-known sites, perhaps meaning fake websites spoofing real ones.

[**Issue 987754: Implement Safety Tip metrics**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=987754&q=safety%20tips&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

> Metrics we want:
>
> - Downloads started
> - Forms submitted
> - Page Info interactions
> - Navigation metrics (# of page loads, navigations to/from safety tip pages, time spent on safety tip pages)
> - Site Engagement metrics (current SE score when loading a safety tip page, change in SE)

This seems to be metrics to judge the effectiveness of Safety Tips displayed
information on user actions. Seems to be pretty invasive.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right about this @harrymc. I thought this could be some kind of malware, but it seems to be a work in progress component instead